# How can I create an SO-style forum?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have a new web app coming out soon. I have an IRC channel for it and would also like to have a forum for my site. I like the idea of SO's reputation system and such and thought I had seen somewhere you could make your own mini SO forum for your website.

Does such a thing exist?
Are there any similar forums to SO?

Comment: Questions about this site should be asked on its [meta site](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/). Questions about Stack Overflow in general should be asked on *the* [Meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). But to answer your question "No, you can't have your own Stack Overflow". The closest you can get is to propose a new site on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Area area51 likely to accept a section for my new project ?

Comment: However, if you are asking about sites *similar* to SO then it's probably just about OK here. However, I would recommend searching [Meta.StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) as clones and other similar software have been discussed there.

Comment: without knowing your project it's difficult to say, but you need to gather enough support (60+ followers) and have a well defined set of possible questions before it can even proceed to beta.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're looking for an installable clone, [meta has a list of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones). You can also have StackExchange [host one for you](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), but you have to go through the approval process and you won't have any control over it.

Answer (score 1):

There was a drupal hack-a-thon which released a stackoverflow clone.
http://drupal.org/project/arrayshift

Comment: I want to see that in action.. is there any demo online?